# Meaning of a red wave line in a single file in PhpStorm

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm

I am using a PhpStorm IDE, and only in one particular file, it started to display the name of the file and the name of the folders routing to that files with red waved underline (like a spell mistake in text-processors). Nothing important it catches my eyes all the time. Anyone know the reason and better how to get rid of it?

Comment: It indicates errors in files. Errors can be observed as lines in the right gutter of the editor, hover the mouse for the error description, click to navigate.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The lines mean that there is an inspection error. The error can be located by looking at that file an examining the right margin for a red bar like this:

[image]

Then you will see, similar to Word, a squiggle under the line of text, something like the following:

[image]

If the inspection looks incorrect, check your settings for the PHP version (File > Settings > Project Settings > PHP > PHP Language Level). If you decide the inspection is invalid, you can turn it off by clicking the place the error appears and then using the red "bulb" to the left:

[image]

Comment: @AnzaVR, glad it solved for you either. Thank you for your well prepared answer. +1.

Answer (score 1):

guess I'll just phrase that as an answer...

Would guess it considers those files (rolled up to folders) to contain errors.  Look on left margin of editor for the files in question.  Guessing they all have a perceived error(s).  PDT / Zend Studio does the same.

see the red X's:  http://imagebin.org/231026

Comment: Since it's not a forum, an answer is the best format :) Also, you are correct in that it's similar, though the errors are generally in the right margin.

Comment: Yeah, started out writing a comment then realized I had written an answer.  Anyway up-voted yours for superior formatting skills using inline images ;)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried hovering over the red lines?  When you do, the actual error message should pop up.

Answer (score 0):

Some times this can happen from if you copy code from the web (gii for example)
with "auto copy" js.
The encoding get mixed up.

If you copy source from Gii, select it manually with the mouse.